# 'Version' conventions for AWS Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, content-security-policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt151
```

This might seem like an obvious question, but when you "Create a custom IAM policy" on AWS, is the 'Version' supposed to be the date that you create it? Is it then good policy to update the Version to today's date whenever you change it? A lot of people just seem to put something from 2012 in there (even in modern tutorials not from 2012)..

Comment: Rather than using template versions like `1.1` and `2.0`, the policies use a **date string** for the version. This sort of makes sense, since the date provides an idea of whether it is a recent version. However, updates to IAM Policy templates and AWS CloudFormation templates tend to be backward-compatible, so there is no need to create a new version. The downside is that it looks very old and outdated. But, it's really just a sign that they take backwards-compatibility quite seriously. Bottom line: Just use the date as shown, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Create a custom IAM policy" on AWS, is the 'Version' supposed to be the date that you create it?

No. It should be  [version of IAM policy language syntax rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html) that you are going to use.  `2012-10-17` is the **latest** version.